# releasing a javascript library for the first time

Tags: licensing, release, distribution, javascript

I'm almost finished working on a useful (at least, in my opinion) JavaScript plugin. Having seen and used many JavaScript packages, both freely licensed (JQuery, YUI, etc) and partly or fully commercially licensed I'm not sure what other factors dictate which license I should release my own under and how to support the plugin.

Some background information on my JavaScript plugin:

- Similar audience and plugin size/impact to [addthis.com](http://www.addthis.com/), although slightly more niche. My plugin doesn't provide any analytics though.
- Uses JQueryUI for user interface, can be expanded upon with there themeing components, etc.
- No other similar tool out there (at least that has become popular).
- Can be easily integrated in to a website.

Questions I have:

1. Should I launch a dedicated website for the plugin, or use something similar to Google Groups? Would a dedicated website bring more kudos perhaps?
2. Would a [Creative Commons Non-Commercial license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/) be a suitable license considering I'm a young developer and perhaps reputation building is more important than my bank managers happiness?

These are the 2 big questions that have been puzzling me for a while now, and I don't know anyone who has been in a similar situation :(

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you seem community, rather than cash driven .. the community will hold the key to what they find best, simplest and acceptable (and what works)

1. What do other plugin developers do? Take their lead. They set the convention and it determines how other people find your plugin. If a Firefox extension only had it's own site then I probably wouldn't find it.
2. What do others use? GPL? LGPL? What does jQuery use? Ask them why?

It might be worth using an online revision control tool like [github](http://github.com/) or [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) so people can contribute bug reports and help your development.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would definitely use something like launchpad or google code.

You get integrated (community enabled):

- source version control
- bug tracking
- ...

for free.

Considering this library is aimed at other (web) developers a shiny website seems a lot less important then the convenient features above (in a known format).

And: congratulations on your first release, of course ;-)

Answer (score 0):

About running site:
For me running dedicated website gives your product more professional look. Hosting on Google groups isn't good choice for all products: you can't build screenshots gallery, own blog, etc. You can build forum by youself if you need it.

Comment: A full site can look showy if the release doesn't have 'fibre'